# Search in NSMutableArray

Tags: swift, search, nsmutablearray

I am wanted to make a search on `NSMUtableArray` with key values to catch the hole object not just an array of values so for example my `NSMUtableArray` return me

```
{id : 1, name : x1}
{id : 2, name : x2}
{id : 3, name : x3}
{id : 4, name : y1}
{id : 5, name : y2}
```

if I am searching of x my code return me

```
{x1,x2,x3}
```

or I want it to return

```
{id : 1, name : x1}
{id : 2, name : x2}
{id : 3, name : x3}
```

my code is :

```
 let arrayy = lstResults.value(forKey: "name")
 let searchTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH   [c] %@", searchBar.text!)
 let array = (arrayy as! NSArray).filtered(using: searchTest)
 filteredTableDataName = array as NSArray
```

please help I tried a lot of stuff but nothing worked form me.

Comment: Why use NSMutableArray? Why not use directly Swift Arrays? `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name BEGINSWITH[c] %@", searchBar.text!); let array = (lstResults as! NSArray).filtered(using: predicate)`

Comment: cause the lstResults is a result of a sqlite query and if I change my code like you said I get this error : CRASH: Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = {}rhs = x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of extracting and filtering the `"name"` values you can filter the array directly, using the corresponding key path instead of “SELF” in the predicate:

```
let array = NSArray(array: [
    ["id": 1, "name": "x1"], ["id": 2, "name": "x2"], ["id": 3, "name": "y3"]])

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH [c] %@", "x")
let filtered = array.filtered(using: predicate)

print(filtered)
```

Result:

```
[{
    id = 1;
    name = x1;
}, {
    id = 2;
    name = x2;
}]
```

Another option is to cast the `NS(Mutable)Array` to a Swift array of dictionaries, and use the `filter()` function:

```
if let a = array as? [[String: Any]] {
    let filtered = a.filter {
        ($0["name"] as? String)?
            .range(of: "x", options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil
    }
    print(filtered)
    // [["id": 1, "name": x1], ["name": x2, "id": 2]]
}
```

Comment: thank you soo much for your help it resolve the problem
if we want to search from two fields we can use 
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name BEGINSWITH [c] %@ OR number BEGINSWITH [c] %@", "x","y")

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray` (or `NSArray` for that matter) are leftovers from the 'Objective-c' era.
For this purpose there is not real need using it or not using Swift's standard generic `Array<Element>` => https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Might I consider creating a struct instead of using a dictionary:

```swift
import Foundation

struct Obj {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

let array = [
    Obj(id: 1, name: "x1"),
    Obj(id: 2, name: "x2"),
    Obj(id: 3, name: "X3"),
    Obj(id: 4, name: "y1"),
    Obj(id: 5, name: "y2")
]

let filteredArray = array.filter { $0.name.localizedLowercase.hasPrefix("x") }
// filteredArray = [
//       Obj(id: 1, name: "x1"),
//       Obj(id: 2, name: "x2"),
//       Obj(id: 3, name: "X3")
// ]
```

Else you would have something like this:

```swift
import Foundation

let array: [[String: Any]] = [
    [ "id": 1, "name": "x1" ],
    [ "id": 2, "name": "x2" ],
    [ "id": 3, "name": "X3" ],
    [ "id": 4, "name": "y1" ],
    [ "id": 5, "name": "y2" ]
]

let filteredArray = array.filter { ($0["name"] as? String)?.localizedLowercase.hasPrefix("x") == true }
```

Comment: This doesn't include the `[c]` part of the predicate, by the way.

Comment: @Sulthan: Maybe use `localizedLowercase` for that purpose, I edited my answer